# <canvas> not working in IE10

Tags: html, canvas, internet-explorer-10

I'm having no luck with this at all. Basically the logo shows the static default instead of the animated  for IE10. Having no issues with any other browser on this.

The logo animation was created using an export from Adobe CS6.

Site: http://barn2media.co.uk/northbromsgrove/

Code:

```
<script>
// Animated Logo
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    images = images||{};

    var manifest = [
        {src:"images/bg.png", id:"bg"}
    ];

    var loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
    loader.addEventListener("fileload", handleFileLoad);
    loader.addEventListener("complete", handleComplete);
    loader.loadManifest(manifest);
}

function handleFileLoad(evt) {
    if (evt.item.type == "image") { images[evt.item.id] = evt.result; }
}

function handleComplete() {
    exportRoot = new lib.north6copycs6450();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(35);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
} 
</script>
```

Hoping somebody can help, many thanks.

Comment: I'm working from a Mac so having to check this using a 3rd party cross browser tool. http://www.browserstack.com/

It works in every browser and platform apart from IE10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out why the logo defaulted to the static image in IE10 but not IE9... It was a PHP issue.

Basically, in order to get the static image to display a selection of images (dependant on the page) in IE8, I used the following to show a static image if the user was browsing in IE8 or below :

```
if ( preg_match("/(?i)msie [1-8]/",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) { 
echo 'IE 8 and below image here';
} else {
echo 'IE 9 and above here';
}
```

**THE SOLUTION**

Apparently by not adding the `\./` after the 1-8 reference, this code included IE10 in the default output.

```
if ( preg_match("/(?i)msie [1-8]\./",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
echo 'IE 8 and below image here';
} else {
echo 'IE 9 and above here';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if IE is set to "Compatibility mode" by pressing `F12` and looking in the top right. If so, set it back to regular IE10 mode.

Comment: Nope, I have double checked and its set to regular mode.